# MySQL using OR in Select Query - when class has been used

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**Info:**  Server version: 5.1.39
**Php:**  5.4
MySQL / phpMyAdmin
**Server:**  Apache
**Code is run via:** Server SQL Query (copy & paste in the phpMyAdmin) or in MySQL Workbench or using a custom shopping cart manager.
**Exports to:** Excel (.csv then to .xlsx for sales reports)
**Other:** I do use a number of tables for referencing

This is part of a larger `SELECT` Query I am running.  For the sake of brevity I have included only the section I currently need looking at.

```
Select  
T5.orders_id As OrdID,  
T3.products_name As ProdName,  
<continues>  
(select value from /*PREFIX*/orders_total T5 where orders_id = T2.orders_id and class = 'ot_reward_points_discount') As ot_reward_points_discount,  
(select value from /*PREFIX*/orders_total T5 where orders_id = T2.orders_id and class = 'ot_reward_points') As ot_reward_points_discount,  
<more data queries>  
Inner Join /*PREFIX*/orders T5 On (T5.orders_id = T2.orders_id)  
<number of joins and final WHERE/DESC>
```

The results end up with me having 2 columns, the data has not merged.  I have been directed in to looking at an `OR` query so that the 2 will result in the one column.  There is no concern with results being overwritten as they 1st `select` & the 2nd `select` are from different configs in my cart, 1 predates the other.

Because the `SELECT` chooses from a class value so it returns in column (not row) data per value I have NO idea how to create the `OR` query so it returns neatly.

Thank you for your help, please let me know if there is further info I need to supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `OR` this way :

```
<continues>  
(select value from /*PREFIX*/orders_total T5 
    where orders_id = T2.orders_id and 
        (class = 'ot_reward_points_discount' or class = 'ot_reward_points')
 ) As ot_reward_points_discount,
<more data queries>
```